# Star-autonomous categories are categorifications of Boolean algebras?

Tags: category-theory, boolean-algebra, monoidal-categories, boolean-ring, categorification

**1. Question**
The [n-Lab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chu+construction) on the Chu-construction says:

> "Armed with just this much knowledge, and knowledge of how star-autonomous categories behave (as **categorified versions of Boolean algebras**, or perhaps better Boolean rigs), the star-autonomous structure on $Chu(C,d)$ can pretty much be deduced (or strongly guessed) […]."

How do star-autonomous categories behave as categorified versions of Boolean algebras or Boolean rigs?

**2. Wikipedia says**
One explanation might be given on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-autonomous_category#Examples):

> "A degenerate example [of a star-autonomous category] (all homsets of cardinality at most one) is given by any Boolean algebra (as a partially ordered set) made monoidal using conjunction for the tensor product and taking 0 as the dualizing object."

I suppose the internal hom of two objects $a,b$ in this category is $\neg a \lor b $, correct? The dual functor is the complement?